# SAS Proc Freq 2 way table remove row and column total

Tags: sas

I need to create a two-way table without row and column total.

here is the code:

```
proc freq data = freq_table1 ; 
    table c * x / norow nocol nopercent ;
    title "x";
run;
```

the output is:

[image]

I actually want:

[image]

Also, does anyone have an idea how to re-order the frequency table from 0-1 to 1-0?

Thank you very much!
JH

Answer (score 1):

The best choice here is probably to use `proc tabulate`, as that gives you more control over the layout.

```
proc tabulate data = sashelp.class ; 
    class age height;
    tables age,height*n;
run;
```